# Why am I getting ReferenceError:value is not defined

Tags: javascript

I am learning about PropertyDescriptors. Why do I get `ReferenceError` in the following code ? I have an object `y`. I want to define a property `foo` in it and have created `get` and `set` functions.

```
// Equivalent definition of 'foo' using a PropertyDescriptor
var y = {};
Object.defineProperty(y, 'foo', { 
  get: function() {
    console.log('in y.foo getter');
    return this.foo;
  },
  set: function() {
    console.log('in y.foo setter. value = ' + value);
    return this.foo;
  },
  enumerable: true,
  configurable: true 
});

y.foo=1
console.log(y.foo)
```

Comment: Because you never defined `value` anywhere...?

Comment: but I read that `If get or set functions are specified, value and writable cannot be specified.`

Comment: If you mean `Object.defineProperty(y, 'foo', {   value:4,
                                    get: function()` then this doesn't work. I get `TypeError: property descriptors must not specify a value or be writable when a getter or setter has been specified`

Comment: You must declare variables before you use them. `value` is not a global variable, nor defined anywhere, so you encounter a `ReferenceError`. That's true regardless of the situation, no matter whether you're trying to define a property or not

Comment: Thanks. I suppose we were thinking about different things for `value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following. You were not passing the argument in `set` function. Also the set function should `set` the value in `variable` and not return like `get`

```js
var y = {};
Object.defineProperty(y, 'foo', {
  get: function() {
    console.log('in y.foo getter');
    return foo;
  },
  set: function(value) {
    console.log('in y.foo setter. value = ' + value);
    foo = value;
  },
  enumerable: true,
  configurable: true
});


y.foo = 1
console.log(y.foo)
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is your setter function is wrong, you forget to set the property value. The modified function will be:

```
set: function(value) {
    console.log('in y.foo setter. value = ' + value);
    foo = value;
},
```

Also, use `foo` instead of `this.foo`.

The working snippet is given here:

```js
// Equivalent definition of 'foo' using a PropertyDescriptor
var y = {};
Object.defineProperty(y, 'foo', {
  get: function() {
    console.log('in y.foo getter');
    return foo;
  },
  set: function(value) {
    console.log('in y.foo setter. value = ' + value);
    foo = value;
  },
  enumerable: true,
  configurable: true
});

y.foo = 1
console.log(y.foo)
```